# change list creation to json with lambda Java

Tags: java, json, lambda

I need to change the response type.

create the response in that part of the code

```
public Map<String, Double> buscaNotavsTipo(Integer idusuario){
    List<NotasMateria> notasMaterias = repository.findAll();
    Map<String, Double> filtered = notasMaterias.stream().
            filter(t -> t.getIdUsuario()== idusuario)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NotasMateria::getTipoNota,
                     Collectors.mapping(NotasMateria::getNotaMateria,
                             averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue))));
     return  filtered;
}
```

he brings that answer

```
  {
tipo_nota: Trabalho
nota: 8.2
tipo_nota: Prova
nota: 5.7
}
```

I need this response format

```
    {
  {
    tipo_nota: Trabalho
    nota: 8.2
  },
  {
    tipo_nota: Prova
    nota: 5.7
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you build the result for the contents of the map?

Comment: Try to map your Map elements to your `NotasMateria` dto again and collect them to list as it was in a first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a specific DTO should be created to represent the output and a list of these DTOs should be returned instead of the `Map<String, Double>`.

Example implementation of the DTO (using Lombok).

Also, a special constructor is provided to facilitate conversion of `Map.Entry<String, Double>` to the DTO instance, which would allow to use the DTO constructor as a method reference.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
class Output {
    private String tipoNota;
    private double nota;

    public Output(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry) {
        this(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); // call all-args constructor provided by Lombok
    }
}
```

Existing method should be refactored to return `List<Output>`:

```java
public static List<Output> buscaNotavsTipoList(List<NotasMateria> notasMaterias, Integer idusuario) {
        return notasMaterias.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getIdUsuario()== idusuario)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NotasMateria::getTipoNota,
                        Collectors.mapping(NotasMateria::getNotaMateria,
                                averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue))))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(Output::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test (using Jackson `ObjectMapper`)

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(
        buscaNotavsTipoList(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new NotasMateria(1, "Trabalho", 8.0),
                        new NotasMateria(1, "Trabalho", 8.4),
                        new NotasMateria(1, "Prova", 5.9),
                        new NotasMateria(1, "Prova", 5.5)
                ),
                1
        ));

        System.out.println(json);
```

Output

```
[ {
  "tipo_nota" : "Trabalho",
  "nota" : 8.2
}, {
  "tipo_nota" : "Prova",
  "nota" : 5.7
} ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but there was an error in that part ".map (Output :: new)"

Comment: Which error?  Please clarify.  If it had an error, the test would have not returned any result.

Comment: I managed to fix it, can you help me with something else? I have a dataNote field in NotesMateria and wanted to sort by that field, how do I do it?

Comment: What is the error in my code that you fixed?

Comment: import error I ended up importing the wrong lib

Comment: Hmm, I did not provide any `import` statements :)  As for sorting, possibly it's better to request a sorted data from repository (if you're using JPA).  Or it's possible to apply `Comparator` to `Collections.sort` or to stream [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) methods.

Comment: how do i do if i want to add a new variable to the dto?

Comment: Extend existing DTO or create a new DTO with this additional field.